# C objective something wrong with if statement

Tags: c, visual-studio

[image: the code]

**This code written in c objective with Visual Studio**

Today a friend of mine sent this code. In university they tried to make a grade calculation program. **The problem is when you write -0 to input and press enter it gives result as the last if statement regardless the if statement is.**

Same conclusion appears when you write +0 etc.
Why this is happening any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Don't post images of code 2. What is "C Objective"?

Comment: Be aware that in all programming languages I'm aware of, the expression `-0` is exactly the same as `+0` which is exactly the same as `0`. BTW it's also pretty basic maths.

Comment: I guess if we mentally cancel the word _objective_, the question makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelWalz don't overlook the famous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero :)

Comment: "...it gives result as the last if statement regardless the if statement is" Can you clarify that a bit, e.g. tell exactly the result it gives

Comment: I would expect the input `-0` to result in `Zero can not be negative`

Comment: I didnt had the code, as I said, a friend of mine sent this code to me as image. Really guys please try to be more tolerant to newbies. Otherwise this is not helping but satisfacting your ego.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of *negative zero* doesn't exist in the C language (and all other languages I'm aware of).

So if you enter `0`, the expression `grade == -0` will be true and therefore your program will display `Zero can not be negative`.

Comment: May be worth to add: a) `if (grade == -0)` is the same as `if (grade == 0)` and b) input `-0` will also display `Zero can not be negative`